# Redefine evil-ex-command

Tags: evil

I use evil and [evil-tabs](https://github.com/krisajenkins/evil-tabs) with Emacs and am quite comfortable with my setup except a few times when I have multiple splits open in a tab, using `:q` ends up closing all the splits in the window. In Vim it will close only the split I am currently in.

I think this part of `evil-tabs.el` is responsible:

```
(evil-define-command evil-tab-sensitive-quit (&optional bang)
  :repeat nil
  (interactive "<!>")
  (if (> (length (elscreen-get-screen-list)) 1)
    (elscreen-kill)
    (evil-quit bang)))
(evil-ex-define-cmd "q[uit]" 'evil-tab-sensitive-quit)
```

I tried doing the following in my `.emacs`:

```
;;; `:quit` ends up quitting more than I intended. So rebind that.
(evil-ex-define-cmd "q[uit]" 'kill-buffer-and-window)
```

Also:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-tabs
  ;; `:quit` ends up quitting more than I intended. So rebind that.
  '(evil-ex-define-cmd "q[uit]" 'kill-buffer-and-window))
```

But `:q` again closes the whole tab. Any clues on how to change or debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've submitted a pull request to fix this in the evil-tabs repo just now, so hopefully it will be applied soon. But in case it isn't or you don't want to wait (anyone coming here just now as I did) you can change evil-tab-sensitive-quit to be:

`(evil-define-command evil-tab-sensitive-quit (&optional bang)
  :repeat nil
  (interactive "<!>")
  (if (> (length (elscreen-get-screen-list)) 1)
      (if (> (length (window-list)) 1)
          (evil-quit bang)
        (elscreen-kill)
        (evil-quit bang))
    (evil-quit bang)))`

The behavior is then:

if tab contains > 1 window, then :q will just close current window
else close tab

and also

if last window in last remaining tab then :q will kill Emacs